# Is there a difference between K Nearest Neighbor = 1 and Minimum Euclidean Distance Classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, k-nearest-neighbour, euclidean

I believe the header asks it all. In this case, I am assuming I am using euclidean distance for KNN as well. Therefore when KNN = 1, I should be looking for only the nearest point, which should be the same as the minimum euclidean distance classifier, correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

KNN needs a distance metric, which might be euclidean distance, and in this case, yes.